# Accessing parent functions from child form in c++

Tags: c++, forms, parent-child

I have seen a couple of solutions to this problem in c# or PHP or even action script, but not in c++.  I have a parent form which calls a child form by newing it and calling ShowWindow on it.  I now need the child form to be able to call one of the parent form's (public) functions.

My first thought was to pass the parent to the child in the child's constructor, but as the child does not know what the parent is I get an error in my child's constructor definition.  The parent knows what the child is (I #included the child form's header file in the parent form's header file), but I can't include the parent's header file in the child's header file without conflict.

Any ideas on better ways or ways to make this work in c++?  Also, I am using C++ Builder 2010 fyi.

I have found the solution to this and will be posting it shortly.

Comment: What GUI library are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mutually recursive classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410637/mutually-recursive-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the best way to do this is as follows:

Parent.h:

```
class Child;
class Parent{
public:
Parent(){
//Constructor
}
```

Parent.cpp:

```
#include Child.h

//declare a child ie. Child chld = new Child(this);
```

Child.h:

```
class Parent;
class Child{
public:
Child(){
//Constructor
}
```

Child.cpp:

```
#include Parent.h

Parent prnt;

//point Tell your child that it's parent is of type "Parent" in it's constructor
 Child::Child(TComponent *Owner){
prnt = (Parent *)Owner;
    }
```

You shouldn't get any conflicts with multiple things being declared in the .h files but you are perfectly able to declare classes without defining them and just define them later.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that of cross-dependency: parent and child classes need to know about each other. But the thing is that they don't need to know too much. A solution is to use a *forward declaration* like this:

In `parent.h`:

```
#include "child.h"

class Parent {
    Child c;
    Parent() : c( this ) {}
};
```

In `child.h`:

```
class Parent; // this line is enough for using pointers-to-Parent and references-to-Parent, but is not enough for defining variables of type Parent, or derived types from Parent, or getting sizeof(Parent) etc

class Child {
public:
    Child(Parent* p) : parent( p ) {}

private:
    Parent *parent;
};
```

Comment: That certainly looks promising.  When compiling though, it tells me that it can't convert 'Parent Instance" to 'Child Instance' on the line where I define my parent constructor to inherit from my child constructor.  Is that telling me that I can't inherit from my child class?

Comment: Probably `Child` was intended to inherit from `Parent`, so it should be `class Child : public Parent {`... by the way, "child" and "parent" are terrible names for an "is-a" relationship!

Comment: No I don't really want Child to inherit from Parent unless that is the only way to do it.  They are fundamentally different classes so inheriting would bring in unnecessary stuff.

Comment: @Kerrek, true, but my example doesn't contain inheritance :) I understood it in the sense of UI control parent-child relationship.

Comment: yeah, unkulunkulu, that is the right kind of relationship I have.  Any idea why it would give me that compiler error?

Comment: @user, your comment here is hard to understand. You should edit your question to contain a minimal example of code which fails to compile or at least specify your compiler and its **exact** error message.

Comment: The funny this is, in my child constructor I already pass it a pointer to the parent through the "Owner" variable.  But when I to to access that pointer from my child, it refers to it as  TComponent type and not as a TEISForm and thus will not let me use any of the parent's functions.

Comment: @user, you should read a good book or resource on object oriented programming, inheritance in particular, answering these kinds of questions one by one will worth a book :D

Comment: Unkulinkulu, I'm not sure what you were getting at with the inheritance. There is no need for that approach. And the code you posted that looked like you were inheriting my "Child" contructor from the _variable_ "parent" instead of the type "Parent" threw me off.  Luckily none of that is necessary.   I have gotten it working in a fairly straightforward manner and will post it here once it allows me to post an official answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    On the constructor in my parent class is gives the error "Cannot convert from "TEISForm * const" to "TForm1 *" Any ideas?
```

This is because `LabelFrm` is declared as a pointer. You should either declare it as a member (I'm not sure right now whether this is correct in VCL), or initialize the pointer using syntax like `LabelFrm = new TForm1(this, "", this)` in the appropriate place (read VCL docs for this, where should the child windows be initialized.

Actually, I get it now, they're not even in parent-child relationship as windows, you can initialize in constructor.

Comment: Right, I was not declaring any instances of Children there.  I new it in my .cpp code, not in my .h file as you might imagine.  I took is as literally as I could from your code, but I can see that that was a mistake.

Comment: I once again recommend you reading a good book on C++, because there was no inheritance of constructors (what a nonsense!), that syntax is called *member initialization list*, you can google it.

Comment: k, sounds useful in other applications.